# sudo password to run playbook for multiple hosts in single group

Tags: ansible

We are using ansible and now we want make some configuration changes on our servers (remote host). We have added multiple servers inside single group in inventory and each server have different password. When we run playbook its asking for sudo password but we can't pass the password for single server because it will be fail for other servers. We are using Digital Ocean cloud so don't have `.pem` key file option.

Can you please help me out how we can pass password for multiple host? 
It should be in secure way.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to provide a unique `sudo` password for each host, you'll want to set the `ansible_become_pass` in either your inventory or in an appropriate file in your `host_vars` directory.

You obviously don't want to store the password in cleartext, so we can use [ansible-vault](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/vault.html) to encrypt the information so that a single password, provided at runtime, permits Ansible to read the passwords.

---

Assuming that we have an inventory with three hosts, `server`, `server2`, and `server3`, we would first ensure that there exists a `host_vars` directory adjacent to our playbook:

```
mkdir host_vars
```

Next, we use the following command to create an encrypted file containing the `ansible_become_pass` variable:

```
ansible-vault create host_vars/server1.yml
```

This will prompt us for a vault password, and then open the file in an editor.  We add content such as:

```
---
ansible_become_pass: secret1
```

Perform the same steps for `server2` and `server3`, using the *same* vault password each time (and setting `ansible_become_pass` to the unique `sudo` password for each host).  We now have the following files:

```
$ find . -type f
./playbook.yml
./host_vars/server2.yml
./host_vars/server3.yml
./host_vars/server1.yml
```

Now, we would run our playbook like this:

```
ansible-playbook playbook.yml --ask-vault-pass
```

This will prompt us for the vault password:

Vault password:

And now Ansible will be able to escalate privileges on the target hosts.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. Its fix my issue. :)

Answer (score -1):

In the playbook use a var_files and store the password and serverIP there (if safe use a py file and get the password and serverIP with that) then check the ipv4 with gather_facts and map the password to that map. Then you can state that in the hosts, become, etc. part.